# Discord Bot TypeError

Tags: python-3.x, discord

I'm trying to make a discord bot game where the player says "hit" and a monster takes a random amount of damage. After the monster takes a certain amount of damage, they die and a new monster appears.
However, when I type in "hit" into discord, I get an error saying

```
TypeError: send_message() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 7 were given
```

This is my code:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def hit (ctx):
    global HP
    damage = random.randrange(50,500)
    HP -= damage
    if HP > 0 :
        await client.say('The monster took', damage, 'damage and has', HP, 'health left')
    else :
        await client.say('The monster has died! Another one approaches...')
        HP = random.randrange(600,1000)
```

Someone please tell me what's wrong and how to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't creating/concatenating the string correctly when passing it to `client.say()`

```
client.say('The monster took', damage, 'damage and has', HP, 'health left')
```

Every time you have a comma here, it is treated as a new parameter to pass to the function.

You need to create the string and pass it as one variable:

```
client.say('The monster took ' + damage + ' damage and has ' + HP + ' health left')
```

Notice this uses `+` rather than `,` to join the string.